# Cannot open tor because of proxy server

Tags: firefox, proxy

I am new to Tor and a basic user and when I try to open Tor i get this message:
The proxy server is refusing connections

Firefox is configured to use a proxy server that is refusing connections.

```
Check the proxy settings to make sure that they are correct.
Contact your network administrator to make sure the proxy server is working.
```

And how do I solve that?

Comment: please post your proxy configuration

Comment: Are you using a plain Firefox or Tor Browser from the Tor Project website?